# Update record if column is not null else create new record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a **users table** and a **tasks table**. I have already many users record and now I need to add tasks for new users as well as for existing users. So for these I am using this query:-

```
$match = ['service_type_id' => 'IS NOT NULL'];

$model->tasksList()->updateOrCreate($match, [
    'service_type_id' => $request->service_description_id,
    'created_by'      => $request->created_by,
]);
```

Here **$model represents user model** and I wanted to update only when the column is not null else create new record but everytime new record is created. Where am I getting wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this with a single Eloquent one-liner. What you're doing there would get interpreted at a string literal, `service_type_id = "IS NOT NULL"`. You'll probably have to do something like this:

```
$action = $model->taskList()->whereNotNull('service_type_id')->doesntExist() ? 'create' : 'update';
$model->taskList()->$action([
    'service_type_id' => $request->service_description_id,
    'created_by'      => $request->created_by
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution. It's working.